# cardano serialization lib - Multiple addresses and stake keys

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, address

I was able to generate a single address following the guide. My question is regarding stake key. Is it necessary to derive a new stake key for each new address or can you just increment .derive(n + 1) and use the same stake key?

```
const utxoPubKey = accountKey
  .derive(0) // external
  .derive(0)
  .to_public();

const stakeKey = accountKey
  .derive(2) // chimeric
  .derive(0)
  .to_public();

const baseAddr = CardanoWasm.BaseAddress.new(
  CardanoWasm.NetworkInfo.mainnet().network_id(),
  CardanoWasm.StakeCredential.from_keyhash(utxoPubKey.to_raw_key().hash()),
  CardanoWasm.StakeCredential.from_keyhash(stakeKey.to_raw_key().hash()),
);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every account **should only use 1 stake key**, and it resides within `m/1852H/1815H/0H/2/0`. Every new address that you generate should use the same stake key. This is so that when you're staking your wallet, it can track your balance across different payment addresses that use the same stake key.

Reference to [Address Derivation](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/concepts/hierarchical-deterministic-wallets) documentation, under the Path Level

Comment: Thank you @dani for the explanation.

Doesn't this make it less private as you can discover the user total balance?

Comment: Yes, it is. In Daedalus wallet, they inform you about it as well. Refer to [Andrew's video on how addresses work](https://youtu.be/NjPf_b9UQNs?t=323)